# Плавное катание и передвижение шара

Tags: html, css, анимация, transform

Есть `div` , делаю эффект будто он катиться. Делаю с помощью `translate` и `rotate`.

Как достичь плавности и большей реальности в конце пути шара, что бы он плавно остановился?

И как просчитывать количество градусов, так как передвижение по оси x всегда на разные расстояние будет?

```js
var deg = 0;

var append = function() {
  deg = deg + 90;
  $("#telo").css({
    "-moz-transform": " translate(350px,0) rotate(" + deg + "deg) ",
    "-ms-transform": "translate(350px,0) rotate(" + deg + "deg) ",
    "-webkit-transform": "translate(350px,0) rotate(" + deg + "deg) ",
    "-o-transform:": "translate(350px,0) rotate(" + deg + "deg) ",
    "transform": " translate(350px,0) rotate(" + deg + "deg) "
  });
  $("#t").append(" |" + deg + "| ")
}

var interval = 0;

$("#btn0").click(function() {
  interval = setInterval(append, 100);
})


$("#btn1").click(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
})
```

```css
div#telo {
  /*transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);*/
  position: absolute;
  width: 95px;
  height: 95px;
  background-color: #22dd66;
  bottom: 100px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  transition: .7s ease;
  -webkit-transition: .7s ease;
  -moz-transition: .7s ease;
  -o-transition: .7s ease;
  border-radius: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
.k {
  width: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #333;
}
div#planka {
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: red;
  bottom: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="telo">
  <div class="k"></div>
</div>

<div id="t">1</div>

<button id="btn0">Start()</button>
<button id="btn1">Stop()</button>

<div id="planka"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Расчет градусов и расстояний**

Диаметр шара - `95px`. За один оборот шара его центр перемещается на длину окружности с тем же диаметром: `3,14 х 95px = 298,3px`.

Один оборот - это поворот на `360deg`. Поэтому рабочее уравнение:

```
alpha / 360 = x / 298,3
```

Если задан поворот на `alpha` градусов, то за время поворота шар прокатится на `alpha * 298,3 / 360` пикселей. Если задано расстояние в `x` пикселей, то за время пути шар повернётся на `x * 360 / 298,3` градусов.

**Плавность хода**

Думаю, что лучший способ - использовать в качестве  [transition-timing-function](https://webref.ru/css/transition-timing-function) не `linear`, а `ease-in` на старте и `ease-out` на остановке.